# How sql understand encrypted connection string in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

I am just leatning in crypting for my application to encrypt web.config asp.net. I have encrypted my `web.config` file using AES. When I run my application db got connected.

I just wan to know how sql able to read encrypted connection string?

Comment: Please [take the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand what kinds of questions should be asked.

Answer (score 1):

"When the page is requested, the .NET Framework decrypts the connection string information and makes it available to your application."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh8x3tas(v=vs.100)

Comment: Hi Thanks!...But am using AES technique..in this case am decided to decrypt my connection strng each time when required....i dont think its efficint...also  i kept my encrypt functiont in session end event....is there any better event where i can keep my encrypt and decrypt fucntion ..?